# Отследить изменения в транзакции

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, transaction, oracle19c

Суть: ввод данных в бд осуществляется с помощью клиентских форм в приложении. Коммит транзакции управляемый - т.е. фиксация изменений не произойдёт, пока пользователь не выполнит все требования формы ввода. Т.е. все сущности в бд создаются только в рамках транзакции и если пользователь откажется от ввода - транзакция откатывается.
Вопрос: возможно ли как-то средствами oracle 19 проверить совершали ли в транзакции create/update/delete операции (select не учитывать) и предупредить пользователя о том, что имеются несохраненные сведения?
Реализовано сейчас так - при изменении/создании/удалении строк или полей программно устанавливается флаг, что форма изменена, а хотелось бы обойтись без этого флага, т.к. нарвался на проблему - пользователь изменяет строку в таблице - флаг изменяется в "1", затем пользователь меняет другую строку - флаг уже стоит в "1" - изменение флага не происходит, затем пользователь отменяет изменения строки - флаг изменяется в "0" - итог: мы потеряли добавление строки.

Comment: Прежде чем пользователь начнёт менять "другую строку", он должен на неё "переместить фокус". А это очень даже повод сбросить флаг. Ещё вариант - не флаг, а нормальная переменная с количеством изменений, которую можно инкрементить. Ещё вариант - массив флагов, по флагу на строку. Есть и ещё куча вариантов. Я уж не говорю о том, что держать открытое соединение с сервером с незавершённой транзакцией, и слать туда изменения по мере ввода - как-то корявенько...

Comment: @Akina , в моем контексте слово "флаг" как раз и обозначает переменную, а не кусок ткани (шутка). Комитить после каждой строки - не позволяет бизнес-процесс (или пользователь вводит все корректно или не вводит ничего).Решение инкрементом - вроде рабочее, но это всего лишь следующий шаг, после решения с одной бинарной переменной (флагом 0/1). Массив флагов- не всегда есть возможность указать размерность массива. При определённых обстоятельствах он - массив - может быть в итоге нулевым.

Comment: @Akina , А насчёт "держать открытое соединение" - не вижу здесь ничего плохого - пользователь копошится внутри своей транзакции и другим не мешает, да и этот механизм (acid) на erp-системах широко используется. Интересует именно способ слежения за изменениями внутри транзакции на уровне бд, а не на уровне ПО.

Comment: *Интересует именно способ слежения за изменениями внутри транзакции на уровне бд, а не на уровне ПО.* Ну тут как бы изменяемая таблица известна, заводишь таблицу отслеживания изменений (ConnectionID-TableName-ChangedRowPrimaryKey), и триггером в неё пишешь ID изменённой в транзакции записи. Соответственно в любой момент можешь из неё выгрести ID всех записей, корректированных в данной транзакции, по номеру своего подключения. Непосредственно перед коммитом - очистить все записи для своего номера соединения (на старте, на всякий случай тоже), ну а при роллбэке оно и само очистится.

Comment: А какой в вашем приложении метод блокировки?

Comment: @0xdb Возможно не понял вопроса, но пока мой ответ: dml, на уровне строки- родителя. Т.е. к родителю нельзя добавить дополнительные связи/свойства, характеристики пока с ним работает пользователь. P.S.: Очень ждал Вашего появления в вопросе :-)

Comment: Я имел ввиду, `select ... from .. for update` используется, другими словами - писсимистическа блокировка?

Comment: @0xdb , именно так

Comment: Хмм, тогда не так просто. Из БД не получится получить информацию, было ли изменение. Можно конечно, что-то придумать, но решение будет достаточно сложным. Проще в приложении считать счётчиком.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нельзя отличить  `select ... from .. for update` от `update`, как   это ни странно. И транзакция открывается, и undo блок будет уже написан.